# Neo4j: Remove labels from the panel, when there is no node related to them

Tags: neo4j

I have removed certain labels from my database using `REMOVE`. Even though those labels don't have any node in the graph now, they are still been shown on the neo4j database panel.

How to remove them so that they don't show up?

Comment: They are still kept in the database. Right now there is no way of cleaning them out afaik. They are created with id's that are saved in your nodes.